# How to make a Chrome Extension available on all tabs while on development (unpacked)?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

I just started developing a small Chrome extension, and following the https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted tutorial, I tried to find a way so that even in developer mode, the extension can be clickable on all tabs.

Right now, the extension is clickable only on pages under `developer.chrome.com` host.

It's probably a silly question, but do we have the possibility to test it, while on development, on other tabs (not under `developer.chrome.com` host)? If yes, how do we set this options? I try to add `<all_tabs>` permission in the manifest, but it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to reload the extension on chrome://extensions page and either reload each tab manually or use chrome.tabs.query + chrome.tabs.executeScript to insert your content script into all tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that following this tutorial https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted, a rule is set in the background.js file that the browser action to execute on other pages.

I had to add the `activeTab` permission and delete code from background.js.

Credit to: https://www.sitepoint.com/create-chrome-extension-10-minutes-flat/

Answer (score 0):

As available here https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/user_interface#browser_action, adding browser_action to your manifest.json as against adding page_action makes the extension available in all tabs.